# HTML5 cache nothing

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat

I don't want to cache anything on my site. my cache.manifest looks like this:
CACHE MANIFEST

```
# Cache manifest version 1.1

CACHE:
#nothing to cache.

NETWORK:
#force no cache
*
```

This is decalred at header

```
<html manifest="/cache.manifest">
```

which is included in each page.

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/html/header.html" %>
```

Contents are still being cached. Firefox still displays the warning "This website {example.com} is asking to store data on your computer for offline use".

**Details specs:**
Apache 2.2
Tomcat 7
cache.manifest is at root.
app is ROOT.war , which is serving root of domain.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Delete the manifest file, if that returns a `404` the cache will be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A manifest is for specifying what content you want to be cached *for offline use*. It has nothing to do with regular caching.

Firefox will prompt for storing data for offline use any time there is a `manifest` attribute on the `html` element, even if the value of it doesn't do anything useful.

If you want to control regular caching, then use [cache control HTTP headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#EXPIRES) such as:

An `Expires` in the past.

```
Expires: Fri, 30 Oct 1998 14:19:41 GMT
```

And/Or `Cache-Control`:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-store
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason behind using a manifest?

HTTP headers are the place for cache control. Add `Cache-Control: no-cache` in your response headers. http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html